# What is the correct form for a Character struct in a VESA/VGA early kernel console?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, osdev

I am currently working on a kernel for x86 (just for fun). I am trying to implement a fairly usable early console, to report on the loading of drivers and to allow me to play with memory during boot if I need to, with the 80x25 character VESA/VGA console located at 0xB8000. I would like to do this with a struct representing a character and its attribute byte. However, I am wondering how to correctly format my Character struct. I currently have:

```
#define CONSOLE_SIZE_X  80  //The length of a line in the console
#define CONSOLE_SIZE_Y  25  //The number of lines in the console
#define CONSOLE_MEMLOC  0xB8000 //The position of the console in system memory

#define ATTR_DEFAULT    0x07 //DOS Default
#define ATTR_ERROR  0x1F //BSOD Colors
#define ATTR_PHOSPHOR   0x02 //"Phosphor" colors, green on black

typedef struct {
    char character = (char) 0x0000;
    char attribute = (char) 0x0000;
} Character; //A VESA VGA character

typedef struct {
    int pos_x = 0;
    int pos_y = 0;

    char defaultAttrib = ATTR_DEFAULT;

    Character buffer[CONSOLE_SIZE_Y][CONSOLE_SIZE_X];


} VESAConsole;
```

The `VESAConsole` struct is for logical purposes only (i.e. it does not represent any important set of positions in RAM); its `Character buffer[][]` will be copied to the actual location of the console by a function `cFlushBuffer(Character* console, Character* buffer)`. This will allow me to implement multiple consoles in early mode for easier debugging on my part (in the manner of `screen` or `tmux`).

So, I really have 2 questions: Is my Character struct correct, and are there any gotchas that I need to be aware of when dealing with the early VESA/VGA console?

Comment: Instead of a `struct`, you could do this with a 3D array `char buffer[CONSOLE_SIZE_Y][CONSOLE_SIZE_X][2]`. I also wonder if `unsigned char` might be appropriate.

Comment: @WeatherVane the `VESAConsole` struct lets me keep track of the cursor position and default coloration for more than one console at a time.

Comment: I meant, *within* `VESAConsole` a 3D array of `char` would be as usable as a 2D array of `Character`, without all the what-if following the answer below.

Comment: @WeatherVane: not necessarily. Without packing, the array might very well end up as having each of the innermost vectors 32 or 64 bit aligned. Just having a single array does not guarantee packing. And a struct is much more readable: `buffer[y][x].attribute` vs. `buffer[y][x][1]` There might still be packing required. The compiler may even decide to align the rows to the next power of two to allow faster calculation of the y-address. One should know the ABI for the architecture very well for this. Or choose an appropriate one as some architectures allow for more than one (e.g. ARM).

Comment: @Olaf I would disagree about the readability if you `#define` the array index so you can go, say `buffer[y][x][ATTR]` and `buffer[y][x][CRAC]`. And I would disagree about the alignment of multi-dim `char` arrays. For example, if you `malloc` memory for a multi-dim `char` array, I have never seen anyone make allowance for extra bytes due to alignment, either when allocating or accessing that array. I *have* seen an exception in bitmap pixel data, but that is a property of the bitmap spec, not of C. Please quote me where it says that.

Comment: So you prefer a #define over a struct field? What is the advantage in this case? There is still no portable guarantee for both array entries to be adjacent without padding (or for two adjacent `Character`s?

Comment: Point is that the standard does not forbid padding of a datatype. It just states that the size of an object as returned by sizeof() must include any padding, so there is obviously no need for the programmer to account for padding manually. It is still very well possible for sizeof(uint16_t) to be 3, for instance. This is of no actual interest for normal programs which have all accesses in the program. It is, however, critical if data structures are accessed from non-ABI instance like hardware, DMA or a CPU with a different architecture.

Comment: ... (cont'ed) --- Point is, any data element may be padded. And for a multidimensional array each dimension is actually a data-element of its adjacent outer dimension. That's what the packing attribute is for (if the architecture does actually support it; this is true for at least x86/64, ARMv4+ and quite likely for MIPS, SPARC and PPC and most (if not all) 8/16 Bitters).

Comment: @Olaf, you have not answered my question in that waffle. Please show me where it says that a multidimensional C `char` array is/can/might be padded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75754/discussion-between-olaf-and-weather-vane).

Comment: No. Seeing as the horizontal dimension is 80, how is that ever not aligned to 8, 16, 32, 64, or 128 bit architecture?

Comment: The standard does not forbid padding elements in general (this includes arrays). It is impossible to show something that does not exist. The question is actually: where does the standard lforbids it? It just requires sizeof() to return the actual size, including any padding. Alignment is - on the other hand - a matter of malloc or the compiler's static allocator. As the pointer to the object is the start of the object, there is acually nothing to account for further.

Comment: You forget about cache-line alignment. Those are much larger than 8 or 16 bytes on some architectures. And a compiler may very well be aware about this. The intel compiler for instance allows to optimize for a very specific CPU version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly yes, your `Character` struct is correct, assuming no padding.

And then as to the gotchas, there are two situations:

- Either you used some known-good code to setup the VGA hardware (e.g. asked the BIOS to do it, asked GRUB to do it, took an example from another OS, ...),
- Or [you did the hardware setup yourself](http://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware).

In the first case, you're good to go. There aren't any really evil gotchas once the setup is done correctly. Just write directly to memory and let the hardware handle it.

In the second, there is an (almost) infinite variety of ways things could go wrong. Graphics hardware is notoriously hard to setup, and although VGA is nothing compared to what modern graphic cards use, it's still far from easy.

Possible side effects include, but are not limited to, blank screens, crashes, burning and/or exploding CRT monitors, etc ..

If you're interested in further reading, you may want to take a look at [the various resources on the OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Resources).

Comment: I would probably point out that, depending on exact compiler, version, options, etc., it's possible that the `struct Character ...` may get padded, which might lead to some surprising results, although that might be slightly non-Standard behavior, as it is just two size-1 no-alignment-restrictions members... But still, it's not unheard of...

Comment: @twalberg Indeed, I'm adding that. Although I wouldn't want to use a compiler that decides to add padding there...

Comment: @tux3: You might have no influence on that, as this is not defined in the standard if two adjacent char fields have padding or not. You might have a look, however at the "packed" attribute (if using gcc). Also you should not use char, int, etc. at that level, but the stdint (since C99) types of the appropriate length. Otherwise you might run into even more problems.

Comment: @Olaf Yes. I though remembering that using two 8bit bitfields of a uint16_t should be a standard way to avoid padding in the middle (although it may still happen at the end), but I can't find that in the standard anymore. Does someone happen to know? This would solve that problem.

Comment: The standard does not guarantee to use no padding at all. For some architectures, there are even no uint8_t available, so it is emulated by 32 bit values of which only the lower 8 bits are used (which includes masking for compares, etc.). The early Alpha CPU is such an example; ARM had no 16 bit types for all variants (signed/unsigned; not sure it it had any at all).

Comment: Also, if packing bytes into larger sized fields, you must be aware of endianess. C11 might worth a look. It provides alingment keywords (among others). However, those were already available as attributes in gcc.

Comment: I much as I like the C standard, sometimes I almost wish it was *less* portable :) I suppose there are always the various compiler-specific #pragmas and attributes left.

Comment: Well, I program embedded systems from 8 to 32 bits. Until now, I got along pretty well with gcc and stdint. You just have to be aware about your platform very well. Also, check out the ABI for the platform you use; for instance, the ARM ABI provides detailed information on alignment, padding, etc. I did not say, the two chars will _not_ get packed. I just want you to be aware of this problem.

Comment: @Olaf that would be types such as uint_8t, uint_16t, etc, right? Do those require a special header file?

Comment: @SilverWingedSeraph: I did mention the name of the header in my comment already;-). Just have a look at the C99 standard (or even better C11 for low-level/bare metal programming). gcc supports C11 partially since 4.7.2 at least (that's what I use), but requires an external heaader for stdatomic (it has, however, the proper builtins already).

Comment: @Olaf Yes, I see that now. Thanks much!